# Сервер многопользовательской игры (Java)

Tags: java, многопоточность, сервер, клиент

Нужна помощь в создании многопользовательской сетевой игры. Это мой первый опыт, поэтому я застрял на моменте связи потоков. Что имеется:
- на сервере есть отдельный поток, который принимает новые подключения клиентов;
- для каждого клиента создаётся отдельный поток, который обрабатывает его запросы.
Проблемы начинаются, когда нужно объединить несколько игроков (потоков) для real-time поединка. Как это сделать на стороне сервера?

Comment: Сомнительная идея поток на игрока. Насколько я помню, создается очередь из сообщений от клиентов с разными приоритетами (несколько очередей по приоритетам) и обрабатываются. При онлайне в 1к у вас будет 1к потоков ???

Comment: Да. Это очень накладно?

Comment: Если это учебный проект - делайте как угодно, набивать шишки бывает полезно. Если что-то более-менее серьезное - возьмите Netty, она возьмет на себя основную часть головной боли по менеджменту потоков.

Comment: Проект учебный, но я планирован получить что-нибудь дельное из него. Но отсылка к фреймворку не отвечает на мой вопрос. Я в принципе не до конца представляю, как можно связать несколько потоков.

Comment: Netty с ее local-thread??? Вы шутите? Обычная nio обертка и ничего более не нужно. По сабжу - напихиваем всех залогинившихся клиентов в мапу (Map<String, GameClient>) и держите всех на одном сокете... Зачем вам потоки для каждого игрока?

Comment: А как быть при большом количестве одновременных запросов? Разве это не скажется на производительности?